# Calculate div height given a known width?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that contains a picture and some text (the image is of the variable size and the text is of the variable length).
Is there any way to calculate the height required to fit all the div content, given that the exact width is predefined?

UPD getting same wrong result when using `$(document).ready()`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function ()
{
  var div = document.getElementById("Content");
  var res = document.getElementById("Result");

  res.innerHTML = div.offsetHeight; // incorrect - returns 252 while the real height is 360 (Firefox, Chrome)
});
```

```css
div
 {
  width: 400px;
 }

 img
 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="Content">

 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

Comment: @Rob isn't this a legit question what makes it off topic?

Comment: @Bobtroopo JS would be fine.

Comment: AFAIK you can't get the correct height before the image load, since you don't know the image size. So I think you'll only could get the correct value after the image load, using `onload` then getting the height inside the callback

Comment: is Jquery is Fine?

Comment: I wonder about the usage for this question. What is the end result you want to achieve, given a couple of images of different sizes? It's quite possible that you don't need to know the image height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `window.onload` instead.

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, i**ncluding all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images**. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired **as soon as the page DOM has been loaded**, without waiting for resources to finish loading. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)</sup>

In your case you need to wait for the image and not only the DOM.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("Content");
  var res = document.getElementById("Result");

  res.innerHTML = div.offsetHeight; 
};
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="Content">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce.
  Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus
  vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et
  malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

Answer (score 5):

To accurately determine the height of the div and the image.
This is because the image will likely finish loading last - if the height of the container is checked before the image is loaded, it will return height without taking the image height into consideration.

A listener should be added to the image so it checks the height once the image loads.

```js
img.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
```

Because the styling is simple, `offsetHeight` and `clientHeight` should work but to include the entire element (with border and margin) use `scrollHeight` as described by [Element.scrollHeight on MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

**The resulting code:**

```html
<div id="Content">
    <img id="Image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />
    ...
</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById("Image");

    function onLoad() {
        var div = document.getElementById("Content");
        var res = document.getElementById("Result");

        res.innerHTML = div.scrollHeight;
    }

    img.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
</script>
```

*The whole example is in a CodeSnadbox here:*

[image: Edit calculate div height - known width - JS]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but you can use javascript to calculate the height of a div.

```
var height = document.getElementsByTagName('div').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this measurement is correct as I'm getting 252 and the actual div looks more like 350 pixels high. Also, I'm getting different measurements immediately after opening the document and after refreshing it (Firefox).

Comment: There is another way : `document.getElementsByTagName('div').getBoundingClientRect().height`. Try this out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Same problem with this one. Maybe it's something about different rendering stages?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are asking to resize the div once the image loads to make the div taller, but just as a side comment, do you know/have you tried background-size: contains?

As specified by MDN:

The contain value specifies that, regardless of the size of the containing box, the background image should be scaled so that each side is as large as possible while not exceeding the length of the corresponding side of the container.

The cover value:

The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container. Try resizing the example below to see this in action.

When combined with background-position I think it can be really useful

Answer (score 1):

if u want to use jquery then this is the way

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Result").html($("#Content").height());
})
```

```css
div
 {
  width: 400px;
 }

 img
 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Content">

 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

Comment: Are you serious? jquery is now considered the reincarnation of the devil, lets them go crazy with pure js.

Answer (score 0):

Not dynamically, since you have the width set it wouldn't be hard to calculate it because it won't change in different screens.
But the only way is doing it MANUALLY USING DEV TOOLS.

If the image and the font will change, you can have a javascript script that after onlaod it will see what height does the div has. (if you need this comment below)

Answer (score 0):

In js you can get the height of any element.
width is not at all needed to calculate height.

since div is some generic tag, add some id to make specific to make sure the right tag is targeted to calculate height

```js
var element_height = document.getElementById("ElToCalHeight").offsetHeight;
alert('Element height ' + element_height);
```

```html
<div id="ElToCalHeight">

 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labo...

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) property.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("Content");
  var res = document.getElementById("Result");

  res.innerHTML = div.scrollHeight; 
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="Content">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce.
  Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus
  vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et
  malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

***DOMContentLoaded*** event is fired when the browser fully loads the HTML and the DOM tree is built, but external resources like pictures  and stylesheets are not yet loaded.
While ***window.onload*** event is fired when the whole page is loaded including styles, images, and other resources.

And you got the height as **252 rather than 360** because the height of the div without your image is 252. For reference, you can run the below snippet.

> This code snippet corresponds to div without image and using
>   window.onload (So height is 252)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("Content");
  var res = document.getElementById("Result");

  res.innerHTML = div.offsetHeight; 
};
```

```css
div
 {
  width: 400px;
 }

/** img
 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}**/
```

```html
<div id="Content">
  <!-- Image tag is not present -->
 <!--<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />-->

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

> This following code snippet corresponds to div with image and using
>   window.onload and now the height will come up to be 360 as expected.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("Content");
  var res = document.getElementById("Result");

  res.innerHTML = div.offsetHeight; 
};
```

```css
div
 {
  width: 400px;
 }

 img
 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="Content">

 <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/82/200/150" />

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Augue interdum velit euismod in. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed.

</div>
<br/>
<span id="Result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% Working! use **Window.onload** function instead of **DOMContentLoaded**

```
  <script>
      window.onload = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById("Content");
      var res = document.getElementById("Result");

      res.innerHTML = div.offsetHeight; 
    };
    </script>
```

Will give your Result!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the method `element.getBoundingClientRect()` after loading. It will return a set of properties such as width and height.