# How to load animation when background has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is to add a class to an element once a background image has been rendered.

Code looks something like this:

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url('/img/bg-banner.webp');
}

#banner-title {
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

#banner-title.start {
  animation-name: fade-in-title;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.99, 0.76, 1);
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <p id="banner-title">Some text</p>
</div>
```

So my question is how do I add 'start' class to #banner-title once the background-image of #banner has finished loading?

p.s. Onload on #banner does not work

Comment: you need onload on the document, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59110298/8620333

Answer (score 1):

Use document.addEventListener see below...

```
<script>    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function backgroundLoaded() {
        //do whatever you want
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. Can you check http://www.imarnold.cf ?

Comment: 'DOMContentLoaded' gets triggered before background image is loaded.
If you check my link, you can see that the text animation runs before the image is done loading.

Comment: how did you added the class ? @Arsi you need to add that functionality in backgroundLoaded() function

Comment: That's what I did

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function backgroundLoaded() {
    document.getElementById('banner-title').className += ' start';
});

Comment: you can not add class like this see the documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp

Comment: I am not using jQuery. I am using plain javascript...
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp

Comment: this is how you can add class ```function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.add("mystyle");
}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203500/discussion-between-arsi-and-vivek).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be sure that the background image has been loaded before some javascript code is executed, you might try this (somewhere *after* the banner):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('banner').classList.add('start');
    // or some other code that requires the image to have been loaded
}
img.src = "/img/bg-banner.webp";
```

NB: You will still need the background-image declaration in your css:

```
#banner {
    background-image: url('/img/bg-banner.webp');
}
```

This should work around any lazy loading of background images by the browser.
I think it's reasonable to assume that if the image has been loaded into the img variable, it will also be available as a background image for the banner.

I know it's a bit of a hack, but it worked for me.